# wp admin plugin: create special pages for specific users

Tags: wordpress

I want to create some users with same roles and want each user could access only his own page(s) which were created by Admin. **Even these page(s) will not show as public**

Like I create 50 users under **Contractors** role and Admin create pages for each user with different contents now each user could only access their own page(s) after login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution [25 Useful Free WordPress Plugins For Multi-Author Blogs](http://www.noupe.com/wordpress/25-useful-free-wordpress-plugins-for-multi-author-blogs.html)